# SQL query, outer join, cte? Need to fix running total with "left" value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, outer-join

I am trying to get this query corrected for days now.  Basically in a group of each `acount_no` and `group`, *only the amount needs to be deducted that is less than the max group*.

Basically, is the account 104 has a maxgroup of 99 and first amount is 75, for that **taken** would be 75 and **left** over amount would be 24, then for the next group B, even if the amount needed is 64, since only 24 is left, group B will be given only 24 and after this nothing is left, so group D will be left with 0.

Basically my table can have values like this

```
DECLARE @table AS TABLE(acc_no INT, [group] CHAR(1), [maxgroup] INT, amount INT)

INSERT INTO @table VALUES
(101, 'A', 70, 0),
(101, 'B', 70, 50),
(101, 'C', 70, 0),
(101, 'D', 70, 20),
(102, 'A', 95, 30),
(102, 'B', 95, 0),
(102, 'C', 95, 5),
(102, 'D', 95, 10),
(103, 'A', 80, 40),
(103, 'B', 80,15),
(103, 'C', 80, 10),
(103, 'D', 80, 5),
(104, 'A', 99.53, 75),
(104, 'B', 99.53,64),
(104, 'D', 99.53, 0.53),

(105, 'A', 21.5, 75),
(105, 'D', 21.5,6)



SELECT t.acc_no, 
    t.[group],
    t.maxgroup,t.amount,
    CASE WHEN t1.assigned = 0 THEN NULL ELSE t.amount END AS taken, 
    CASE WHEN t1.assigned = 0 THEN NULL ELSE (t.maxgroup - t1.assigned) END [left]
FROM @table t
OUTER APPLY(SELECT SUM([amount]) AS assigned 
            FROM @table t1 WHERE t1.acc_no = t.acc_no AND t1.[group] <= t.[group]) t1
```

This is what I am expecting in the result:

```
 acc_no group   maxgroup    amount  taken   left
101 A   70      0   NULL    NULL
101 B   70      50  50  20
101 C   70      0   0   20
101 D   70      20  20  0
102 A   95      30  30  65
102 B   95      0   0   65
102 C   95      5   5   60
102 D   95      10  10  50
103 A   80      40  40  40
103 B   80      15  15  25
103 C   80      10  10  15
103 D   80      5   5   10
104 A   99      75  75  24
104 B   99      64  24  0    --<<
104 D   99      0   0   0
105 A   21      75  21  0
105 D   21      6   0   0
```

Unfortunately my query is giving negative values for `left` column for `acc_no=104`.

Comment: Hi. It is good to see the code part of a [mcve]. But it needs a clear specification. "Basically" does not make fuzziness clear. (When it does not introduce or summarize clear full details then its presence suggests that the writer knows they are not clear yet wrote unclearly anyway. Why did they?) Your description of how the output is a function of the input is unintelligible. Please use enough words, phrases & sentences to be clear. Do not try to cram everything into one sentence or paragraph. Refer to intermediate expressions & example values for them.

Comment: Thanks much Philipxy, I shall keep that in mind. Still learning the standards of stackover flow. Its been very helpful for me, thank you so much for your patience with me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close:

```
CASE 
  WHEN t1.assigned = 0 THEN NULL 
  WHEN t.maxgroup < t1.assigned THEN 0 --<< that's it
  ELSE (t.maxgroup - t1.assigned) 
END [left]
```

But my suggestion is:

```
SELECT t.acc_no, 
    t.[group],
    t.maxgroup,
    t.amount,
    CASE 
      WHEN t.amount = 0 THEN 0
      WHEN t.maxgroup < (t.running_total-t.amount) THEN 0
      WHEN t.maxgroup < t.running_total THEN t.amount - (t.running_total - t.maxgroup)
      ELSE t.amount
    END taken,
    CASE 
      WHEN t.maxgroup < t.running_total THEN 0
      ELSE t.maxgroup - t.running_total
    END [left]
FROM (
  SELECT t.acc_no, 
      t.[group],
      t.maxgroup,
      t.amount,
      SUM(t.amount) OVER(PARTITION BY t.[acc_no] ORDER BY t.[group] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) running_total
  FROM stock t
) t
order by 1, 2
```

This one will do only one scan of source table. Instead of many loops with subquery approach.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ce2f5/12

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you so much, that worked great.. One question, why do we need to order by  and what is 1,2 doing? I do want the running total to be computed based on order of groups but order by 1,2 doesn't look like is doing that. Please suggest.

Comment: `order by` is sorting final output, it does not affect running total. `1, 2` - allowed but not welcomed method of referencing output columns by number, works for `order by` only. It's fine for testing query, not for prod (bad style).

Comment: Thanks much.. So in this case 1,2 would be columns t.acc_no and t.group?

Answer (score 1):

To keep your query logic, you can keep track of previous row total for each group, like so:

```
SELECT t.acc_no, 
    t.[group],
    t.maxgroup, t.amount, 
    CASE WHEN A.previous_assigned + t.amount <= t.maxgroup THEN t.amount
    ELSE CASE When (t.maxgroup - A.previous_assigned) > 0 Then (t.maxgroup - A.previous_assigned)
        ELSE 0
        END 
    END AS taken, 
    CASE WHEN  (t.maxgroup - A.previous_assigned - t.amount) <= 0 THEN 0 
    ELSE (t.maxgroup - A.previous_assigned - t.amount) 
    END AS [left]
FROM @table t
OUTER APPLY(SELECT SUM([amount]) AS assigned, (SUM([amount]) - t.amount) AS previous_assigned
            FROM @table t1 WHERE t1.acc_no = t.acc_no AND t1.[group] <= t.[group]) As A;
```

Comment: Thanks much, if I will add the following lines (107, 'A', 100,20),
(107, 'B', 100, 35),
(107, 'D', 100, 65),
(107, 'C', 100, 50) in the table, that wouldnt give the correct results. I think I have got the solution now, thank you so very much for helping here.